# Button tag with Image while submit issue

Tags: java, jsp

I am using a

```
<button name="btn" value="Save"><img src="/image/save.png"/>Save</button>;
```

in my JSP page. when user lands on page, User is seeing that button and image on left to text of Save. but when the Form is submitted, in request.getParameterValues(), it is showing the value of button name:
`(name=value as btn = img src="/image/save.png"/ Save)`

and I am restrcting special character like `<` sign due to security concern. So I am expecting the request.getParameterValues for btn should return me "Save" and not complete `<img` tag.

Has anybody came across this issue? I dont want to add image using css.

Thanks in advance.

Nilesh

Comment: Please reformat your code using CTRL+K, it's hard to read...

Comment: Did you read the comments I left for Jonny's answer? Did you read my answer carefully before you made your choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking but I'm guessing you're trying to display an image as a button?

Maybe try this:

```
<input type="image" src="/image/save.png" alt="Save" name="save" value="save"/>
```

then in your JSP or Servlet:

```
String save = request.getParameter("save");
```

Comment: No, I am able to show the button and image on jsp page. Issue is with the submission. When i submit the form, the value for Save is <img src="imagename"/>Save. but I am expecting the value should be Save only and not the complete <img src which is after <button><img src=""/></button>

Comment: @Nilesh have you got a syntax error because I just tried this with Eclipse: `<button name="btn" value="Save"><img src="/image/save.png"/>Save</button>` and `request.getParameter("btn")` gives me `Save`.

Comment: <button type="submit" class="positive" name="Save"> <img src="<c:url value="/images/apply.png"/>" alt="Save" />Save</button>
In java, I have 
String paramName = (String) e.nextElement();
Object paramValue = request.getParameterValues(paramName);
so the value for ParamName is Save and Value for it is 
<img src="/images/apply.png" alt="Save"/>Save

Comment: Hey Surprisingly it works when i tried with IE8 and FF, it request gets the value as Save in IE8 and FF but same thing doesn't work with IE7. in IE7, it returns the value with <img tag. 
any idea, how to deal in IE7 why it pass the value associated to Button including <img tag?

Comment: With an input type image, browser will send the coordinates of the point clicked on the image along with the name. In you example, it will be something like save.x=13&save.y=20 instead of save=save.

Comment: @dragon66 that's true but if you specify a name and value it will also send `&save=save`.

Comment: @Jonny: out of the three browsers I tested using your example, all of them sent save.x and save.y to the server. The only browser which also sent save=save is chrome. So the reliable way to know whether the button is clicked or not is to check save.x and save.y.

Comment: @dragon66 Oh, I didn't know different browsers made a difference. I'm using Chrome. Thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IE, that's the expected result at least when I tested it on IE8, it sent the text between button tag (with the HTML tag stripped off) as value to the server. FF and Chrome both return the correct value set as the value attribute. Go test [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_button_name).

Comment: Yes, you are right. but due to security concern I do not allow <> symbol in any request. so when form is submitted, the request parameter for Save button is <img src="imagepath"/>Save which is causing a problem while request is submitted to spring.

Comment: @Nilesh: please really make sure you are receiving string with html tag. In you original post, I didn't see them. If you really get html tag and you are worrying about security, use a regex to remove them.